# Can't add watches to variables declared inside namespaces. VS2013

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, watch

I'm currently unable to watch variables declared on a namespace when debugging on Visual Studio 2013.

If I right click the variable Y want to watch, the watches windows says the *namespace* is not declared.

Debugging the following program and trying to watch either *dave* or *lara* from the *function()* fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
namespace ages{
    namespace daughter{
        int lara = 1;
    }
    namespace son{
        int dave = 3;
    }
    int function(){
        int age_sum = daughter::lara;
        age_sum += son::dave;
        return age_sum;
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("Sum: %d\r\n", ages::function());
}
```

Here's a picture of the debugger, notice the result is correct but that I canot add a watch.

[image: MSVC window]

Comment: ages::daughter::lara should work

Comment: I works. But why do I need to add the ages:: namespace from the namespace itself? (see function).

Comment: `But why do I need to add the ages:: namespaces from the namespace itsel`  Because you're using a *debugger*, not a *compiler*.  Debuggers can have their quirks, and specifying all the qualifying names may be one of those things you'll have to live with.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, That's strange because `age_sum` is not required to be fully qualified.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/368850/vs2008-debugger-problem-with-globals-in-namespace

Comment: Broken by-design. If I want to use the debugger, my code has to become overly verbose.